# Django - decorators and error messages

Tags: python, django

This seems like a simple question but I can't seem to find a simple answer.  Django seems to give this nifty simple way of limiting access to places using the permission required or login required decorators but I can't see from the Django docs how one would pass an error message (maybe using the messages framework).  If I have to roll my own decorator to do this, what is the point of the django decorators?  Do they just not show any error messages?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  They redirect to a login page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll assume you simply avoided reading this

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

> login_required() does the following:
>
> If the user isn't logged in, redirect
>   to `settings.LOGIN_URL`, passing the
>   current absolute path in the query
>   string. Example:
>   `/accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/`.
>
> If the user is logged in, execute the
>   view normally. The view code is free
>   to assume the user is logged in.

There are no "error messages".  Error messages are rude.  And largely useless.  They're often a sign of bad design.

Generally, you don't need a million tiny little explanations.  Indeed, the default login page works fine for 80% of the use cases.
If you need to clarify the situation, you can provide your own HTML form.  You can use the ordinary template context to add additional information.  You have the [Messages Framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages) for presentation of extra messages on the login page.

Comment: I did read that, thanks.  Many websites that require logging in redirect you with an error message saying, you must be logged in to view that page.  Are you saying I should just have an html page for the purpose of displaying "you must login" and another html page for the purpose of displaying "you don't have permission"?  To me that seems silly.  If you could get redirected back to your homepage which has a login form on it and just provide a message that says "please log in" or "you don't have the right permission" that would make more sense

Comment: Maybe for something as simple as, needing to be logged in, but what if you need specific permission to access something and you're logged in but don't have the required permission.  Wouldn't it make sense to display some kind of message saying what kind of permission you need?

Comment: @JPC:  "Wouldn't it make sense to display some kind of message saying what kind of permission you need?"  Not really.  They're not allowed, and that's the way the site is designed.  If they need to be allowed, they either need a different username or they need to call the help desk.  These are not subtleties.  Permissions need to be simple and obvious.

Comment: @S.Lott: "You can use the ordinary template context to add additional information. You have the Messages Framework for presentation of extra messages on the login page."  None of this can be done with decorators though, is what I'm saying.  If I want to put something in the context or use the messages framework, there's no way to do that from a login_required decorator.

Comment: @JPC: None of it is done with decorators.  Correct.  It's not *supposed* to be done entirely with decorators.  It's expected that you'll customize the login page.  That's the way Django works.  The decorator -- by itself -- in isolation -- is not supposed to be the entire solution to Authorization.  Authorization is pervasive throughout the site's design and implementation.

Comment: @S.Lott: So then decorators are useful for the simple cases where you just want to redirect to the login page or maybe a static "you don't have permission to access this" page.  If you want to do anything more specific, you would have to do more

Comment: @JPC: If you want to do anything more, you would have to do more.  Authorization is pervasive throughout the site's design and implementation.

Comment: ""There are no "error messages". Error messages are rude. And largely useless. They're often a sign of bad design."" Yes, let's just throw the user to the login screen with no explanation, it's way better...

Comment: @foljs: The login screen is clear, simple and effective.  It doesn't need any additional explanation.  If you want to write  a few paragraphs of "about this site" and some "privacy" and other information that's all good.  But it's simply a redirect to a page.  Nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're conflating security and permissions with Django's authentication system. For the most part, Django's tools are mainly designed for separating users into two groups: authenticated (logged in), and anonymous. This makes sense for 90% of the web sites out there, as you don't really need too much differentiation (maybe another for a hidden admin, but that's an edge case, rather than the norm).

The permission_required decorator is a very simple hook for people wishing to redirect people who failed to have permissions to go to the login page. At some point, though, this is not enough. If you need a specific permission and the user does not have it, how does redirecting them to the login page help them?

In this case, it's so easy to roll your own decorator using the messages for specific errors. One such example:

```
def user_has_permissions(method):
    return user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('my_permission'), login_url='/permission-denied/')(method)
```

Comment: I suppose that would be the best option.  I noticed that in the django docs, login_required only supports login_url in the development version (1.2 doesn't support it).  But in 1.2, login_url is supported for permission decorators.  Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

You will send the user an automatic error message.. You'd have to look how to over-ride..

Comment: do you mean, overriding the the decorators and creating my own?